# SQL Developer Language won't change

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an issue with SQL developer where the GUI language won't change as it shows  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNvvf.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNvvf.png]

Now I have tried the solutions where I added the following to `sqldeveloper.conf` file and even tried it on the `ide.conf`. I even tried reinstalling sqldeveloper yet nothing is resolved.

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en 
AddVMOption -Duser.region=US
```

Here's the full sqldeveloper.conf file:

```
IncludeConfFile ../../ide/bin/ide.conf

AddVMOption -Duser.language=en 
AddVMOption -Duser.region=US 

#https://community.oracle.com/thread/4337814
AddVMOption -Xss100m

#Set our usage tracking URI
AddVMOption  -Dide.update.usage.servers=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/sqldeveloper/usage.xml

#Disable the AddinPolicyUtils
AddVMOption  -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true

#Draw performance change
AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false

#font performance
AddVMOption -Dwindows.shell.font.languages=

AddVMOption -Doracle.ide.startup.features=sqldeveloper

AddJavaLibFile ../lib/oracle.sqldeveloper.homesupport.jar
AddVMOption -Doracle.ide.osgi.boot.api.OJStartupHook=oracle.dbtools.raptor.startup.HomeSupport

#Configure some JDBC settings

AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false  
AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false

# The setting below applies to THIN driver ONLY for others set this to false. 
# Refer to OracleDriver doc. for more info.
AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.useFetchSizeWithLongColumn=true

AddVMOption -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true
AddVMOption -Dorg.netbeans.CLIHandler.server=false




#Disable remote entity resolution
AddVMOption -Doracle.xdkjava.security.resolveEntityDefault=false

# Avoid rendering exceptions on some graphics library / java / Linux combinations
# enable only if you are getting
# java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData cannot be cast to sun.java2d.xr.XRSurfaceData
# ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188495/how-can-i-work-around-the-classcastexception-in-java2d-bug-id-7172749
# AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.xrender=false

# Bug 27758406 JAVAFX JFXPANEL USAGE (WELCOME/INSTANCE VIEWER) CONFUSES SWING WINDOW SCALING
AddVMOption -Dprism.allowhidpi=false

IncludeConfFile  java11.conf

IncludeConfFile  sqldeveloper-nondebug.conf
```

Comment: any jvm settings should go in the product.conf file

Comment: That looks like a rendering glitch rather than a foreign language :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Bizarre.... that's English, but letters are being replaced with those two characters on in the alphabet (e.g. "Oracle Database XE" becomes "Qtceng Fcvcdcug ZG").  I'm not sure what could cause this but I would guess the JDK SQL Developer is using has got messed up.  Did you download the version of SQL Developer that included a JDK, or are you using a separate JDK?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Thanks for the heads up! At first I downloaded it and was using a separate JDK, now when I redownloaded it, I downloaded the version that had the JDK included. However in the product.conf, the path for the JDK was still made on the separate JDK for some reason. When I placed the path of the JDK that came with the sqldeveloper. Everything is working well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the solution was to re-download SQL Developer with the included JDK and ensure that SQL Developer was configured to use this JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the step-by-step as in the below image. The language that you want to change depends on the added language code, for example, en, vn........
[image]